# thorough guide to Locks/Transactions/Isolation Levels in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions, locking, isolation-level

Is there a good tutorial/guide/blog post/book chapter/screencast/etc that attempts to comprehensively cover everything having to do with locks, transactions, and isolation levels in ActiveRecord?  (preferably relevant to Rails 4.0)

There's a brief section in the guides, and of course some API docs, but it's a really important and (for me) hard-to-understand domain, and it's my first time trying to take data integrity seriously in my Rails app.  I'd like to get a good understanding so I can do it properly.

**List of Known Resources**

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#locking-records-for-update
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions.html
- https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/392eeecc11a291e406db927a18b75f41b2658253 ("Support for specifying transaction isolation level" commit -> Rails 4.0)
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/59-optimistic-locking-revised

Comment: i would recommend looking for guide/book on mysql transactions and see how it is recommended to use. Then you can write ruby code that will utilize those recommendations.

Answer (score 11):

I would check out Chapter 5 of [The Rails 3 Way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321601661) for now, particularly Section 5.5 on Database Locking. I would also look at the [ActiveRecord::Locking source](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/locking), [ActiveRecord::Transactions source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb), and the [transaction_isolation test case](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/test/cases/transaction_isolation_test.rb) as the code is very readable and if you're going to need some down in the weeds answers, it's there in the code!

Answer (score 3):

I found [Differences between transactions and locking](http://makandracards.com/makandra/31937-differences-between-transactions-and-locking) on Makandropedia a pretty useful starting point to learn the difference between transactions and locks.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: If link dies we can replace it with archived copy. I feel most of it is essential.

Comment: This article refers to a method `Lock.acquire()` but that does not seem to be referenced anywhere else, let alone in Rails docs.